# Why isnt my player movement system working when I change the rectangle to a circle?

Tags: python, pygame

I made a system player movement system that works well with a rectangle but when I change it to a circle it just stops working!

```py
import pygame as pg

# making screen
screen = pg.display.set_mode((500, 500))
# making clock to count ticks
clock = pg.time.Clock()
# making a rectangle
rect = pg.Rect(200, 400, 100, 10)
circ = pg.draw.circle(screen, (0, 255, 0), [300, 300], 10, 0)
speed = 6

done = False

while not done:
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            done = True
    # moving the rectangle with player input
    keys = pg.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pg.K_a] and not rect.x <= 0:
        rect.x -= speed
    if keys[pg.K_d] and not rect.x >= 400:
        rect.x += speed
    if keys[pg.K_s] and not rect.y >= 480:
        rect.y += speed
    if keys[pg.K_w] and not rect.y <= 320:
        rect.y -= speed
    if keys[pg.K_t]:
        circ.y -= speed

    screen.fill((40, 40, 40))

    pg.draw.rect(screen, (150, 200, 20), rect)
    pg.draw.circle(screen, (0, 255, 0), [300, 300], 10, 0)

    pg.display.flip()
    clock.tick(30)
```

I only want to move the circle with the 't' key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must draw the circle at the center of the rectangle that sourounds the circle (`circ`), not at (300, 300):

<s>`pg.draw.circle(screen, (0, 255, 0), [300, 300], 10, 0)`</s>

```py
pg.draw.circle(screen, (0, 255, 0), circ.center, 10, 0)
```

---

Note, [`pg.draw.circle`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.circle) does not create a circle object. It draw a circle on the screen and a [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) objet that rounds the circle. Therefore only create `pygame.Rect` object that indicates the position and size of the circle:

```py
import pygame as pg

# making screen
screen = pg.display.set_mode((500, 500))
# making clock to count ticks
clock = pg.time.Clock()
# making a rectangle
rect = pg.Rect(200, 400, 100, 10)
circ = pg.Rect(290, 290, 20, 20)
speed = 6

done = False
while not done:
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            done = True
    # moving the rectangle with player input
    keys = pg.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pg.K_a] and not rect.x <= 0:
        rect.x -= speed
    if keys[pg.K_d] and not rect.x >= 400:
        rect.x += speed
    if keys[pg.K_s] and not rect.y >= 480:
        rect.y += speed
    if keys[pg.K_w] and not rect.y <= 320:
        rect.y -= speed
    if keys[pg.K_t]:
        circ.y -= speed

    screen.fill((40, 40, 40))

    pg.draw.rect(screen, (150, 200, 20), rect)
    pg.draw.circle(screen, (0, 255, 0), circ.center, circ.width // 2, 0)

    pg.display.flip()
    clock.tick(30)
```

Comment: Ok thats good info but I want to move the circle independantly

Comment: @anothaone `pg.draw.circle(screen, (0, 255, 0), circ.center, 10, 0)`

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add coordinate-variables for the circle:

```
cx, cy = 300, 300

if keys[pg.K_t]:
    cy -= speed

pg.draw.circle(screen, (0, 255, 0), [cx, cy], 10, 0)
```